# Is it fine to flag one line answers or link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags, answers

Recently I noticed one person who gave two answers in one hour. In the first answer he/she just added one link and another answer he just added few words in the answer. Stack Overflow provides a comment feature so I think they should use this instead of giving very short answers without description or more info about answer.

So my confusion is if it's okay to flag these particular types of answers, who just give answers for getting reputation only.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question?

Comment: Instead of flagging, leaving a comment for the OP is preferred.  Or, if you're feeling especially helpful, edit the relevant content of the link into the answer (with attribution).

Comment: Those aren't links.  Could you give us actual links?

Comment: [Fist one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300886/advertisment-sdk-in-flappy-bird/22301050#22301050) and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297489/error-with-chartboost-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-crypto-sign/22297549#22297549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I declined the flags on those posts. [In the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300886/advertisment-sdk-in-flappy-bird/22301050#22301050), the question itself was faulty. The answer was about as good of an answer as you could expect for that question. For the second, [I left a comment detailing how the OP could improve their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297489/error-with-chartboost-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-crypto-sign/22297549#comment33885522_22297549).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion on that question. I didn't know that the flag was already asked about on meta.